# How to see if a line exists in a file in python?

Tags: python, file

I am creating a high scores database, and I need to check if a line in the file exists in a file that I created.

Would I use a for loop to see if a string exists in the file in python.

Thanks

Comment: what have you tried so far? then when you do so if there's a error come over here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're only looking for a yes-or-no answer, and the line is static, you could simply do

```
search = "This is the line I'm looking for.\n"
with open("highscores.txt") as file:
    if any(line == search for line in file):
        print("Found it!")
    else:
        print("Move along.")
```